# Why for loop is behaving differently?

Tags: java

Here I am trying to reverse a number using for loop but when n=1234 it gives the output 432 only.
Please explain why for loop behaving differently.

When i tried the same problem with while loop using condition while(n>0) it worked as expected and gave the desired output

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int n=sc.nextInt();
int rev=0;
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    int temp=n%10;
    n=n/10;
    rev=rev*10+temp;        
}

System.out.println(rev);
```

expected output is 4321 when n=1234 but it is giving output as 432

Comment: Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: Hint: consider printing your intermediate results in order to better understand what your code is doing. You learn programming by being creative. Asking others for explanations should be your last resort, not the first.

Comment: You're starting your `i` at index 1, which skips your first character. Use `i=0;` instead.

Comment: even when i am starting from 0 it is giving the same output

Comment: while(n>0) will be a better loop condition in your case.

Comment: Why do you even need the `i` ?

Comment: @GhostCat i tried the same thing ..printing intermediate results but results were 4 3 2..i tried dry run with the code ..and result was the expected one i.e 4321..i dont know whats going wrong?

Comment: @ManojBanik yes while loop  worked perfectly fine but i am baffled beacuse of for loop's unexpected behaviour

Comment: @MohammedMortaga would you please explain in detail

Comment: @Abhishek The for loop's behavior is not unexpected at all.  You're telling it to stop the loop when `i<=n` is true.  As you iterate through the loop, the value of `n` changes from *4321*, to *432*, to *43*, to *4*.  Meanwhile, you're incrementing `i` every loop, so it goes from *1* to *2* to *3* to *4*.  Thus in the final loop, both `n` and `i` are *4*.  This means that before the final iteration of the loop starts, `i<=n` is true since they're both *4*, which causes the loop to stop.  You don't need `i` for anything (it's not used in the loop), so you should use a while loop, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like you need to read more about loops in java

when you use `for` loop, you go thru all the numbers from 1 (in your case) to n

and when you use `while` you go until n is 0

you can see there is a different between the values you end up with, i really suggesting you to watch some more toturials before moving on :)

Comment: but when n=1234 so i=1 to i<=n should work i guess...no?

Comment: @Abhishek but you chaning n :) n is at the end equals to 0

Comment: even when i tried with i=1 to i<=n the result was same 432

Comment: @Abhishek no problem :) mark the answer a correct if so :)

Answer (score 0):

Understand what you want to achieve first: For reversing a number

Input:  num

(1) Initialize reverse_num = 0

(2) Loop while num > 0
     (a) Multiply reverse_num by 10 and add remainder of num
          divide by 10 to rev_num
               reverse_num = reverse_num*10 + num%10;
     (b) Divide num by 10

(3) print reverse_num

The for loop you are using is taking all the values in consideration starting from 1 to 1234 (1, 2, 3, 4,5, 6......1234)

When you are using while loop you just have one condition if num>0 which is what we need, hence it works.

```java
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
          int num=sc.nextInt();
          int reversed = 0;
            while(num >0) {
                int digit = num % 10;
                reversed = reversed * 10 + digit;
                num /= 10;
            }
          System.out.println(reversed); 
        }
```

Comment: here to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try smth like this:

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int n=sc.nextInt();
int rev=0;
while(n>0)
{
   int temp=n%10;
   rev=rev*10+temp;
   n=n/10;
}
System.out.println(rev);
```

Will be better to use while

Answer (score 0):

How the algorithm work with while and why you need to cut untill n=0(1234 as example):while(do this untill n == 0).

## First try:

first line:temp=n%10 so temp=1234%10=4.second line:n=n/10 so n=1234/10=123
third line: rev=rev*10+temp so 0*10+4=4;

## Next try:

first line:temp=n%10 so temp=123%10=3,second line:n=n/10 so n=123/10=12,
third line: rev=rev*10+temp so 4*10+3=43;

## Next try:

first line:temp=n%10 so temp=12%10=2 second line:n=n/10 so n=12/10=1.2(1,int)
third line:rev=rev*10+temp so 43*10+2=432;

## Final try:

first line:temp=n%10 so temp=1%10=1
second line:n=n/10 so n=1/10=0.1(0,int),third line: rev=rev*10+temp **so REV it's 432*10+1=4321**;